# Instantiating a session scoped managed bean from another request scoped bean

Tags: java, jsf

I need to instantiate a session bean from another request scoped bean & set values to that bean. How can I do that from another bean ?

Actually I need to instantiate the `usersession` bean after user has successfully logged in & I need to set the `user` managed property of that session bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually instantiate it the usual way and put it in [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29):

```
UserSession userSession = new UserSession();
userSession.setUser(user);
externalContext.getSessionMap().put("userSession", userSession);
```

In name of proper design, I'd rather delegate the job to JSF by just injecting it as `@ManagedProperty`:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Login {

    @ManagedProperty("#{userSession}")
    private UserSession userSession;

    public String login() {
        // ...

        if (user != null) {
            userSession.setUser(user);
        }

        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: pretty cool.. Thanks. Just a small clarification when a managed property from another bean is set in current bean then, it is not the copy but a reference to the original property so when the local property is changed the original would be changed, right ?(this is where I was confused)

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it just points to the same reference. Any changes will be reflected forth and back. Java is OO, you know.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `user` property of your `usersession` bean upon login. It does not matter if it is instanciated before login, because its `user` property will remain null until login is done.

And inject `usersession` bean in your request coped beans with `@javax.inject.Inject` annotation.